# 8 shades of grey (sliding puzzle)

Tags: c, game, opengl

I've written a smaller version of [15 puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle) in C, using OpenGL 3.3 and freeglut. I've found a place you can [play it online](http://mypuzzle.org/sliding) to get familiar. I'm new to OpenGL, so I have no idea if I'm doing this in the right way. Nevertheless, this game compiles and works as intended on my 64-bit HP COMPAQ laptop with Intel HD graphics card and lubuntu 15.04 (64-bit) OS installed. I would be glad if you would point out the major (and minor) mistakes I made to avoid them before moving on to bigger projects.

~200 CLOC + comments

**Makefile**

```
all: 8

8: main.o render.o
    gcc main.o render.o -lglut -lGLEW -lGL -o 8

main.o:
    gcc -c -std=c99 main.c

render.o:
    gcc -c -std=c99 render.c

clean:
    rm -f main.o
    rm -f render.o
```

**main.c**

```
/* 8 shades of grey - a sliding puzzle */

/* OpenGL dependencies */
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

/* Standard dependencies */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* Home dependencies */
#include "render.h"

/* Constants */
#define WIN_TITLE "8 shades of grey"
#define WIN_WIDTH 600
#define WIN_HEIGHT 600

int empty_tile_loc = 8;
int board_loc_contents[9] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};

/* Swaps tiles */
void swap_tiles(int is_x, int diff) {
    empty_tile_loc += diff;
    board_loc_contents[empty_tile_loc - diff] = board_loc_contents[empty_tile_loc];
    board_loc_contents[empty_tile_loc] = 8;
    if(is_x) {
        if(diff < 0) offsetx[board_loc_contents[empty_tile_loc - diff]] += 0.666;
        else offsetx[board_loc_contents[empty_tile_loc - diff]] -= 0.666; }
    else {
        if(diff < 0) offsety[board_loc_contents[empty_tile_loc - diff]] -= 0.666;
        else offsety[board_loc_contents[empty_tile_loc - diff]] += 0.666; }
    glutPostRedisplay(); }

/* Keyboard arrow callback */
void kboard_arrow_callback(int key, int mouse_x, int mouse_y) {
    switch(key) {
        case GLUT_KEY_LEFT:
            if(empty_tile_loc % 3 != 0) swap_tiles(1, -1); break;
        case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:
            if(empty_tile_loc % 3 != 2) swap_tiles(1,  1); break;
        case GLUT_KEY_UP:
            if(empty_tile_loc > 2) swap_tiles(0, -3); break;
        case GLUT_KEY_DOWN:
            if(empty_tile_loc < 6) swap_tiles(0,  3); break; } }

/* The main function */
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    /* Initializing freeGLUT */
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitContextFlags(GLUT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE);
    glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);
    glutInitContextVersion(3, 3);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutInitWindowSize(WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT);
    glutCreateWindow(WIN_TITLE);

    /* Initializing GLEW */
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE; /* to render VAO */
    if(glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "GLEW failed to initialize!\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE; }

    /* Setting freeGLUT function callbacks */
    glutDisplayFunc(draw_callback);
    glutSpecialFunc(kboard_arrow_callback);

    /* Initializing VBOs, VAO, shader program and variables... */
    if(!draw_initialize()) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Drawing failed to initialize!\n");
        draw_terminate();
        return EXIT_FAILURE; };

    /* Main loop! */
    glutMainLoop();

    /* Exiting... */
    draw_terminate();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS; }
```

**render.h**

```
#ifndef RENDER_H
#define RENDER_H

/* Amount of tiles */
#define NUM_BUFFERS 8

/* Shader variables */
float offsetx[NUM_BUFFERS];
float offsety[NUM_BUFFERS];

/* Self-explanatory public draw functions */
int draw_initialize(void);
void draw_terminate(void);
void draw_callback(void);

#endif
```

**render.c**

```
#include "render.h"

/* OpenGL dependencies */
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

/* Standard dependencies */
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* Size of infolog char array - used to report errors */
#define INFOLOG_SIZE 1024

/* Drawing data */
GLuint VAO;
GLuint VBO_ids[NUM_BUFFERS];
GLfloat VBO0[] = {-1.00, 1.00,0,-.333, 1.00,0,-1.00, .333,0,
                  -1.00, .333,0,-.333, .333,0,-.333, 1.00,0};
GLfloat VBO1[] = {-.333, 1.00,0, .333, 1.00,0,-.333, .333,0,
                  -.333, .333,0, .333, .333,0, .333, 1.00,0};
GLfloat VBO2[] = { .333, 1.00,0, 1.00, 1.00,0, .333, .333,0,
                   .333, .333,0, 1.00, .333,0, 1.00, 1.00,0};
GLfloat VBO3[] = {-1.00, .333,0,-.333, .333,0,-1.00,-.333,0,
                  -1.00,-.333,0,-.333,-.333,0,-.333, .333,0};
GLfloat VBO4[] = {-.333, .333,0, .333, .333,0,-.333,-.333,0,
                  -.333,-.333,0, .333,-.333,0, .333, .333,0};
GLfloat VBO5[] = { .333, .333,0, 1.00, .333,0, .333,-.333,0,
                   .333,-.333,0, 1.00,-.333,0, 1.00, .333,0};
GLfloat VBO6[] = {-1.00,-.333,0,-.333,-.333,0,-1.00,-1.00,0,
                  -1.00,-1.00,0,-.333,-1.00,0,-.333,-.333,0};
GLfloat VBO7[] = {-.333,-.333,0, .333,-.333,0,-.333,-1.00,0,
                  -.333,-1.00,0, .333,-1.00,0, .333,-.333,0};
GLfloat *VBOs[NUM_BUFFERS] = { VBO0, VBO1, VBO2, VBO3, VBO4, VBO5, VBO6, VBO7 };
size_t VBO_sizes[] = { sizeof(VBO0), sizeof(VBO1), sizeof(VBO2), sizeof(VBO3),
                       sizeof(VBO4), sizeof(VBO5), sizeof(VBO6), sizeof(VBO7) };
float offsetx[NUM_BUFFERS] = {0.00};
float offsety[NUM_BUFFERS] = {0.00};
float color_r[NUM_BUFFERS] = {0.00, .125, .250, .375, .500, .675, .750, .875};
float color_g[NUM_BUFFERS] = {0.00, .125, .250, .375, .500, .675, .750, .875};
float color_b[NUM_BUFFERS] = {0.00, .125, .250, .375, .500, .675, .750, .875};

/* Shader program data */
GLuint shader_prog_id;
GLuint vshade_offsetx;
GLuint vshade_offsety;
GLuint fshade_color_r;
GLuint fshade_color_g;
GLuint fshade_color_b;

const GLchar *vert_src =
"#version 330\n"
"uniform float offsetx;\n"
"uniform float offsety;\n"
"layout (location = 0) in vec3 Pos;\n"
"void main() {\n"
"   gl_Position = vec4(Pos.x + offsetx, Pos.y + offsety, Pos.z, 1.0); }\n";

const GLchar *frag_src =
"#version 330\n"
"uniform float color_r;\n"
"uniform float color_g;\n"
"uniform float color_b;\n"
"out vec4 FragColor;\n"
"void main() {\n"
"   FragColor = vec4(color_r, color_g, color_b, 1.0); }\n";

/* Function declarations */
int draw_initialize(void);
void draw_callback(void);
void draw_terminate(void);
void vbo_init(void);
int shader_init(const GLchar **v_src, const GLchar **f_src, GLint *v_size, GLint *f_size);
int find_shader_vars(void);
int compile_shader(GLuint shader);
void shader_err(GLuint id, GLchar *msg);

/* Initializes drawing */
int draw_initialize(void) {
    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    vbo_init();
    GLint vsrcsize = strlen(vert_src);
    GLint fsrcsize = strlen(frag_src);
    if(!shader_init(&vert_src, &frag_src, &vsrcsize, &fsrcsize)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Shader program failed to initialize!\n");
        return 0; }
    if(!find_shader_vars()) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not find all shader variables!\n");
        return 0; }
    return 1; }

/* Draw callback */
void draw_callback(void) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glUseProgram(shader_prog_id);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_BUFFERS; ++i) {
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO_ids[i]);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);
        glUniform1f(vshade_offsetx, offsetx[i]);
        glUniform1f(vshade_offsety, offsety[i]);
        glUniform1f(fshade_color_r, color_r[i]);
        glUniform1f(fshade_color_g, color_g[i]);
        glUniform1f(fshade_color_b, color_b[i]);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, VBO_sizes[i]/sizeof(GLfloat)); }

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glutSwapBuffers(); }

/* Draw termination */
void draw_terminate(void) {
    glDeleteProgram(shader_prog_id); }

/* Initializes VBOs and VAO */
void vbo_init(void) {
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glGenBuffers(NUM_BUFFERS, VBO_ids);
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_BUFFERS; ++i) {
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO_ids[i]);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO_sizes[i], VBOs[i], GL_STATIC_DRAW); } }

/* Prints shader program error */
void shader_prog_err(GLuint id, GLchar *msg) {
    GLchar infolog[INFOLOG_SIZE];
    glGetProgramInfoLog(id, INFOLOG_SIZE, NULL, infolog);
    fprintf(stderr, "%s '%s'\n", msg, infolog); }

/* Initializes shader program */
int shader_init(const GLchar **v_src, const GLchar **f_src, GLint *v_size, GLint *f_size) {
    GLint success;
    shader_prog_id = glCreateProgram();
    GLuint v_shader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLuint f_shader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(v_shader, 1, v_src, v_size);
    glShaderSource(f_shader, 1, f_src, f_size);
    if(!compile_shader(v_shader)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Vertex shader compilation failed.\n");
        glDeleteShader(v_shader);
        glDeleteShader(f_shader);
        return 0; }
    if(!compile_shader(f_shader)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fragment shader compilation failed.\n");
        glDeleteShader(v_shader);
        glDeleteShader(f_shader);
        return 0; }
    glAttachShader(shader_prog_id, v_shader);
    glAttachShader(shader_prog_id, f_shader);
    glLinkProgram(shader_prog_id);
    glDetachShader(shader_prog_id, v_shader);
    glDetachShader(shader_prog_id, f_shader);
    glDeleteShader(v_shader);
    glDeleteShader(f_shader);
    glGetProgramiv(shader_prog_id, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
    if(!success) {
        shader_prog_err(shader_prog_id, "Error: failed to link shader program:");
        return 0; }
    glValidateProgram(shader_prog_id);
    glGetProgramiv(shader_prog_id, GL_VALIDATE_STATUS, &success);
    if(!success) {
        shader_prog_err(shader_prog_id, "Error: failed to validate shader program:");
        return 0; }
    return 1; }

/* Finds location of uniform variables in shader program */
int find_shader_vars(void) {
    vshade_offsetx = glGetUniformLocation(shader_prog_id, "offsetx");
    vshade_offsety = glGetUniformLocation(shader_prog_id, "offsety");
    fshade_color_r = glGetUniformLocation(shader_prog_id, "color_r");
    fshade_color_g = glGetUniformLocation(shader_prog_id, "color_g");
    fshade_color_b = glGetUniformLocation(shader_prog_id, "color_b");
    if(vshade_offsetx == -1 || vshade_offsety == -1) return 0;
    if(fshade_color_r == -1 || fshade_color_g == -1 || fshade_color_b == -1) return 0;
    return 1; }

/* Compiles shader, returns if was succesfull, prints error msg if not */
int compile_shader(GLuint shader) {
    GLint success;
    glCompileShader(shader);
    glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if(!success) {
        GLchar infolog[INFOLOG_SIZE];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, INFOLOG_SIZE, NULL, infolog);
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to compile shader: '%s'\n", infolog); }
    return success; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Makefile

Your Makefile isn't as useful as it could be, since it doesn't rebuild anything when you change the source: there's no dependency information in it. Also if you want to change your compiler or compiler flags, you'll need to do that all over the place. Adding a new source file requires adding three lines and modifying (at least) two others.

So, I'd start off with:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic
```

These are standard variable names, people will be familiar with them.
Then you could:

```
SOURCES=main.c render.c
LIBS=-lglut -lGLEW -lGL
```

Now you've got all your source files and the necessary libraries in one place, easy to change down the line.

```
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.c=.o)
```

(See [Substitution References](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Substitution-Refs.html#Substitution-Refs).) This generates the name `foo.o` from `foo.c`: got all your object files now too. So you can:

```
all: 8

8: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJECTS)
```

(See [Automatic Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html).)
And... that's it. Make knows how to build `.o` files from `.c` files, and will use `$(CC)` and `$(CFLAGS)`, so no need to create those rules yourself. If the built-in rule doesn't suit your need, create a generic one, e.g.:

```
%.o: %.c
  @echo Building $@ from $^
  @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $^
```

This isn't quite complete, in particular you have no build dependency on your header file. If you want to go further, though that would be a bit overkill here, look for generating dependencies automatically, e.g. [generate dependencies for a makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313778/generate-dependencies-for-a-makefile-for-a-project-in-c-c).

#### Header

```
float offsetx[NUM_BUFFERS];
float offsety[NUM_BUFFERS];
```

These should be declared `extern`.

#### Code

Unfortunately I don't know OpenGL, so can't really comment on that.

But your bracing style is *very* strange for me, very hard to read and makes your code way too compact. I'd urge you to put the closing braces on their own line. And put a space between `if` (and `while`) and the  conditional.

Examples:

```
int compile_shader(GLuint shader)
{
  GLint success;
  glCompileShader(shader);
  glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
  if (!success) {
    GLchar infolog[INFOLOG_SIZE];
    glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, INFOLOG_SIZE, NULL, infolog);
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to compile shader: '%s'\n", infolog);
  }
  return success;
}
```

```
void swap_tiles(int is_x, int diff)
{
  empty_tile_loc += diff;
  board_loc_contents[empty_tile_loc - diff] =
      board_loc_contents[empty_tile_loc];
  board_loc_contents[empty_tile_loc] = 8;
  if (is_x) {
    if (diff < 0)
      offsetx[board_loc_contents[empty_tile_loc - diff]] += 0.666;
    else
      offsetx[board_loc_contents[empty_tile_loc - diff]] -= 0.666;
  } else {
    if (diff < 0)
      offsety[board_loc_contents[empty_tile_loc - diff]] -= 0.666;
    else
      offsety[board_loc_contents[empty_tile_loc - diff]] += 0.666;
  }
  glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

If you want to practice "ultra-dense" C, you could hop over to [Programming Puzzles and Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions) for a real challenge, but otherwise don't try and minimize your LOC count.

```
int draw_initialize(void);
void draw_callback(void);
void draw_terminate(void);
```

You've already got those in the header, not needed in `render.c`.

Comment: Thank You. I've taken your advice on makefile, extern variables and redundant function declarations.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feedback. You might want to wait a bit more before accepting an answer though - I didn't touch the OpenGL part which is probably the most important. If you accept an answer, it is less likely that other people will look at your question.

Comment: Okay. Yes, the OpenGL part is the most important. I'm just learning it and I'm afraid of getting bad habits early on.